# Alert boxes in Python?

Tags: python, alerts

Is it possible to produce an alert similar to JavaScript's alert("message") in python, with an application running as a daemon.

This will be run in Windows, Most likely XP but 2000 and Vista are also very real possibilities.

Update:
This is intended to run in the background and alert the user when certain conditions are met, I figure that the easiest way to alert the user would be to produce a pop-up, as it needs to be handled immediately, and other options such as just logging, or sending an email are not efficient enough.

Comment: I suppose a better way to phrase this is as a "Background process" not a daemon.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

what about this:

```
import win32api

win32api.MessageBox(0, 'hello', 'title')
```

Additionally:

```
win32api.MessageBox(0, 'hello', 'title', 0x00001000)
```

will make the box appear on top of other windows, for urgent messages. See [MessageBox function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) for other options.

Comment: For more info on this function I found this: http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32api__MessageBox_meth.html

Comment: I'm getting `ImportError: No module named win32api`.

Comment: install the package with **`easy_install PyWin32`**. Unfortunately there is no built-in solution for that aside from the very restricted `raw_imput()`, right?

Comment: Or you can use ActiveState's version of Python, http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads, which comes with PyWin32 already installed.

Answer (score 20):

For those of us looking for a purely Python option that doesn't interface with Windows and is platform independent, I went for the option listed on the following website:

https://pythonspot.com/tk-message-box/  (archived link: https://archive.ph/JNuvx)

```
# Python 3.x code
# Imports
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox

# This code is to hide the main tkinter window
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

# Message Box
messagebox.showinfo("Title", "Message")
```

You can choose to show various types of messagebox options for different scenarios:

- showinfo()
- showwarning()
- showerror ()
- askquestion()
- askokcancel()
- askyesno ()
- askretrycancel ()

*edited code per my comment below*

Comment: One thing...the message box won't close after I press ok with your code.... Why?

Comment: I noticed that I didn't put a () after withdraw. Try that. Other than that, I don't have any problems with the meesagebox closing. Are you using it exactly as written? What version of python are you using?

Comment: I have the same issue as @AIM_BLB. Clicking ok won't close the window

Comment: @AbdulkarimMalkadi What version of python and what version of tkinter are you using?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [**PyAutoGui**](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) to make alert boxes
First install pyautogui with pip:

```
pip install pyautogui
```

Then type this in python:

```py
import pyautogui as pag
pag.alert(text="Hello World", title="The Hello World Box")
```

Here are more message boxes, stolen from Javascript:

- `confirm()`
  With Ok and Cancel Button
- `prompt()`
  With Text Input
- `password()`
  With Text Input, but typed characters will be appeared as *****

Answer (score 3):

GTK may be a better option, as it is cross-platform. It'll work great on Ubuntu, and should work just fine on Windows when GTK and Python bindings are installed.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

dialog = Gtk.MessageDialog(None, 0, Gtk.MessageType.INFO,
            Gtk.ButtonsType.OK, "This is an INFO MessageDialog")
dialog.format_secondary_text(
    "And this is the secondary text that explains things.")
dialog.run()
print "INFO dialog closed"
```

You can see other examples [here](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dialogs.html). ([pdf](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/python-gtk-3-tutorial/latest/python-gtk-3-tutorial.pdf))

The arguments passed should be the gtk.window parent (or None), DestroyWithParent, Message type, Message-buttons, title.

Comment: Somehow this gives me an error "no module named repository". Seems like it is outdated?

Comment: @Kev1n91 You on Ubuntu 16.04 or newer? Try it in python3. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use win32 library in Python, this is classical example of OK or Cancel.

```
import win32api
import win32com.client
import pythoncom

result = win32api.MessageBox(None,"Do you want to open a file?", "title",1)

if result == 1:
 print 'Ok'
elif result == 2:
 print 'cancel'
```

The collection:

```
win32api.MessageBox(0,"msgbox", "title")
win32api.MessageBox(0,"ok cancel?", "title",1)
win32api.MessageBox(0,"abort retry ignore?", "title",2)
win32api.MessageBox(0,"yes no cancel?", "title",3)
```

Comment: you are importing pythoncom and win32com.client for nothing

Answer (score -4):

Start an app as a background process that either has a TCP port bound to localhost, or communicates through a file -- your daemon has the file open, and then you `echo "foo" > c:\your\file`. After, say, 1 second of no activity, you display the message and truncate the file.

Comment: That seems like an awful lot of work, and it does not solve teh problem.

Comment: You did not specify the conditions upon which the dialog box would be displayed.  I assumed inter-application dependencies.

Comment: I said I needed to produce an alert box, this does not display an alert.