# How can I use an alert dialog with Python in linux?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, cross-platform

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177287/alert-boxes-in-python), but I'm using Xubuntu, so the win32 api is obviously not available. Is there some alternative I can use?

I just need to have a simple window pop up with a message, from a python script.

Comment: There's an answer on that question that mentions gtk: would that work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20461473/5031339

Comment: That would work, I think, but it looks like it has a lot of prerequisites. Tkinter's the way to go (at least on Ubuntu). Thanks!

Comment: GTK is very good, and powerful, but Tkinter's handy for simple stuff. And it's a lot easier to learn than GTK. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this with Tkinter, which is cross-platform, and commonly bundled with the standard Python package.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
tkMessageBox.showwarning('alert title', 'Bad things happened!')
```

(On Python 3, you need to change the first line to `import tkinter as tk`. And the `import tkMessageBox` line becomes `from tkinter import messagebox`, and a matching change is required for the last line).

The next two lines create a root window for the application (which all Tkinter programs need), but then make that window invisible. And finally we display our alert.

You *may* need to install python-tk (i.e. `sudo apt-get install python-tk` in Ubuntu distributions) before using Tkinter - it's not installed by default on some distributions.

Comment: Wow. That was easy. Thanks!

Comment: On some Linux builds, the included Python installation does not include Tkinter, because [Tcl itself isn't pre-installed](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/How_to_install_Tkinter). This solution won't work on those systems. Just something to look out for.

Answer (score 9):

To create a notification rather than a dialog box that needs to be dismissed, you can use `notify-send` as shown below. This also does not require installing `python-tk` or other packages.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["/usr/bin/notify-send", "--icon=error", "This is your error message ..."])
```

See the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/notify-send.1.html) for more options.

Answer (score 2):

This answer based on PM 2Ring answer:

I have some issue with closing the message box so I did it this way:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
tkMessageBox.showwarning('Title','Are you sure?')
root.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

For Python3:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
messagebox.showwarning('alert title', 'Bad things happened!')
```

You need to install tkinter:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Another solution is using `pyautogui`

```
import pyautogui as pag
pag.alert(text="Bad things happened!", title="alert title")
```